# Is it possible to get null instead of out of range exception in array?

Tags: c#

```
bool?[,] logicTable = new bool?[width, height];

for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
   for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)      
       if (logicTable?[i, j - 1] == true)

{...}
```

At this point I am getting index out of range exception (becouse j-1 gives -1). Is it possible for this expression :

```
logicTable?[i, j - 1]
```

to quickly return the null value if one of indexing values is out of range?

Comment: Why not just iterate starting from `1`?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: the ugly way is to capture the index out of range exception and return null

Comment: This is also a situation to not use `?[`... if the array is `null`, it will still be null on the next iteration, so you should do one test for null and skip the whole loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible if you are using standard arrays (as in your sample) as they are always 0-indexed and always throw on out-of-bounds access.

You can create your own wrapper that returns `null` for out-of-bounds cases which may make some algorithms easier by automatically providing [sentinel values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value):

```
class SafeOutOfBoundsArray
{
    public SafeOutOfBoundsArray(bool?[,] array)
    {
        this.array = array;
    }
    bool?[,] array;
    public bool? this[int r, int c] 
    {
        get {
            if (array == null ||
                  r <0 || c < 0 || 
                  r>=array.GetUpperBound(0)|| c>=array.GetUpperBound(1))
                return null;
            return array[r,c];}
    }
}
```